# Inserting "lng": into string at specific point

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write a script to replace the 
`{"lat":-32.1814184, -64.4201269}` to `{"lat":-32.1814184, "lng":-64.4201269}`.
what is the expression to find the first occurrence of `,` from `}` and replace.

My code is given below:

I am trying to replace the string with the required. I wrote a function, but

```
<script>
    function getActualData(){ 
        while(true){
            var textData=document.getElementById("tss").innerHTML;
            var repeats = textData.match(/}/g).length;
            if(repeats=0) { break;}
            dIndex = textData.indexOf("}");
            if(dIndex>0){
                var s=textData.substring(dIndex-11,dIndex);
                alert(s);
                document.getElementById("tss").innerHTML=textData.replace(s,",lng:"+s);
            }
                else
                break;
        }
    }
</script>


<div id="tss">
{"ID":xxx,"Name":xxx,"emailID":xxx@aol.com,"Address":Provincial 51, Cordoba,xx ,lat":-32.1814184, -64.4201269}, {"ID":xx,"HolderName":xx,"emailID":x@aol.com,"Address":Department - Cordoba 51, xx, "lat":-32.2714158, -64.6214281}
</div>
<script>getActualData();</script>
```

Comment: What is the script that you tried to run?

Comment: Hi Jerry, Please let me know how can I do it? Thank u

Comment: Why not use valid JSON in the first place? What does generate this `<div id="tss">` markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most pleasant solution but here's one in python:

```
import re
string = '''{"ID":xxx,"Name":xxx,"emailID":xxx@aol.com,"Address":Provincial 51, Cordoba,xx ,"lat":-32.1814184, -64.4201269},{"ID":xx,"HolderName":xx,"emailID":x@aol.com,"Address":Department - Cordoba 51, xx, "lat":-12.2714158, -64.6214281} '''
group = re.findall(r'\"lat\":[-]*[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,\ [-]*[0-9]+\.[0-9]+',string)
for coordinate_pair in group:
     string = string.replace(coordinate_pair,coordinate_pair.replace(', ',', "lng":'))
```

- group is a list of every coordinate pair
- it is then iterated through, replaced with "lng" injected
- the fixed coordinate pair is then replaced into the string

Comment: Thank u Roy, there are multiple commas in that data

Comment: Thank u Roy! I dont know Python. I will try to implement above code in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` like follows:

```
function getActualData(){
    var textData = document.getElementById("tss").innerHTML;
    var result = textData.replace(/"lat":[^,]+, /g, "$&\"lng\":");
    return result;
}

alert(getActualData());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JuAq8/)

Details of the regexp:

`"lat":` matches literally "lat":`

`[^,]+,` matches all characters except comma, followed by a comma and a space.

For the replace, `$&` is the match, and `\"lng\":` will add `"lng":` to the match.

Comment: Thank you very much Jerry! Will learn RegExp,.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user3645137 If that worked, let me know :) You can also click on the tick outline near to my answer to mark it as the one that solved your question.

Comment: {"PID":"xxx","PNM":"Xxxx","EID":"dssd","ADD":"dssf", "lat":39.4840108, "lng":-0.7532808999999999}, {"PID":"zzz","PNM":"dssdd","EID":"dsd","ADD":"Ss", "lat":40.46366700000001, "lng":-3.74922}, {49.342559, 12.113349}, {"PID":"dsdsd","PNM":"dsss","EID":"dsfs","ADD":"dsfsfs", "lat":49.34303, "lng":12.10917}    Plz let me know how can i remove {49.342559, 12.113349},  from above sequence. have to submit the code in 3 hrs

Comment: @user3645137 I'm not sure whether it's the right way or not because there isn't much details, but, you could perhaps use `textData.replace(/\{-?[\d.]+,\s*[\d.]+\}/g, "");`

Comment: Hi Jerry, Manually removing cannot be done.
Is there a regex for the following pattern

{55.679762, 12.59119},  {44.610146, 6.05587}, {-24.72937, 15.408325},  {31.355662, -9.799418},  {37.753837, -122.403172},

Comment: @user3645137 Does the above regex work? The one I have put in the comments?

Comment: I have tried replacing with Notepad++ and it solved the issue.Thank you.

Comment: @user3645137 Okay, great! Hm, also, you can mark only one answer as accepted, unfortunately, and you need some more reputation points to be able to upvote/downvote =/